# Obtain a higher order of accuracy for a particular Runge Kutta method than the maximum order for general problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am going through a past exam paper, but there is a solution which I don't understand. Thanks a lot!

The problem has 2 parts, and the part I don't understand is in part B, but it is related to part A. I will put the part I don't understand in italic.

**(A) Determine, with justification, the maximum order of the Runge-Kutta method with Butcher Table
[image: Butcher table for the Runge-Kutta method]**

So I have solved it and the maximum order is 2.

However, Part B really confuses me.

**(B) Suppose the method in question is applied to the linear, scalar ODE $y'=ky$, where $k$ is a constant; is it possible to obtain a higher order of accuracy for this special case than the maximum order (for general problems) obtained in part (A)?**

Answer: The answer is yes.

The order conditions for order 3 include the following 2 equations:
$$bc^2=\frac{1}{3}, \quad b^TAc=\frac{1}{6}$$

***The first one is associated, in the error analysis, with the elementary differential $f_{yy}f^2$. The second derivative of f vanishes so the term is not present.
The second one is associated with $f_y^2f$. Using this and $b_1=\frac{1}{2-2\alpha}$, $b_2=1-b_1$, we get
$$b_1\alpha^2+(1-b_1)(2\alpha-\alpha^2)=\frac{1}{6}$$***
$$\implies \left(\frac{1}{2-2\alpha}\right)\alpha^2+\left(1-\frac{1}{2-2\alpha}\right)(2\alpha-\alpha^2)=\frac{1}{6}$$
$$\implies \alpha^2-\alpha+\frac{1}{6}=0$$

And we see $b^2-4ac=1-4\times 1\times\frac{1}{6}>0$, so there are two real solutions.

---

So what I don't get is where does that function f come from, and where does $f_{yy}f^2$ and $f_y^2f$ come from?

Answer (score 1):

For general autonomous ODE of the form $\mathbf{y}' = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y})$ the truncation error of some Runge-Kutta method can be expressed in terms of derivatives of $\mathbf{f}$.

Actually, it is
$$
\boldsymbol\delta = \left(\sum_i b_i - 1\right) \mathbf{f}
+ h \left(\sum_i b_ic_i - \frac{1}{2}\right) \mathbf{f}_y \mathbf{f} + \\
+ h^2 \left(\sum_{ij} b_ia_{ij}c_j - \frac{1}{6}\right) \mathbf{f}_y \mathbf{f}_y \mathbf{f}
+ h^2 \left(\sum_{ij} b_i\frac{c_i^2}{2} - \frac{1}{6}\right) \mathbf{f}_{yy} \mathbf{f} \mathbf{f} + O(h^3)
$$
To get a method of order $O(h^3)$ for general $\mathbf{f}$ you need to zero all the coefficients before the $\mathbf{f}$ and its derivatives. But in this specific case when $\mathbf{f}$ is linear you don't need to zero the term that corresponds to $\mathbf{f}_{yy}\mathbf{f}\mathbf{f}$
$$
\sum_{ij} b_i\frac{c_i^2}{2} - \frac{1}{6}.
$$